# How to set up debugging in renderer process ( Electron js )

Tags: javascript, debugging, electron

I just want to stop at a certain line in the renderer process ( i write 'debugger'), but it does not stop, unlike older electron versions, how can I fix this. I use bozon

Answer (score 0):

1. Let debugger command at the line you want stop (as you did).
2. Make sure you open dev tool before catch that line.

> mainwindow.webContents.openDevTools();

3. In devtool don't deactive breakpoint as image

[image: deactive breakpoint]